# Adding Logo and other image in header

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a logo in the header but when I add it, it shifts the email and the contact number (they are also in header) downwards.

How do I fix this? I am using a simple img function to add the logo into header.

And I also want to show a small email icon and a small phone icon before the email and the phone number in the header.

How can I do this?

And also I do not want this background image to show up on the entire page. It should take only 1/4th of the page. What can I do to make this possible?

[image]

```
<header id="big">
<img src="capture.png"/>

<style type="text/css">
    body{
    background-image: url(ny.jpg);}

</style>
    <h3>info@xyz.com  +123-456-789 <h/3>

</header>
```

My CSS:

```
    #logo{
        display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Can you post your code or a link to your page?

Comment: And you can post your CSS, too

Comment: please add a screenshot of how it looks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this also:- http://jsfiddle.net/9wa8j/1/

You said you want something like image and the text adjacent to it. Right?
  So, according to what I understood , I tried something like this:-

```
.s{
 display:inline-block;

 }
```

Check this link:-
http://jsfiddle.net/9wa8j/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9wa8j/3/          You can change the margin-top:0px; according to your need and your problem will surely be solved. Do inform if its working.

Comment: Yes, it's working. What was I doing wrong?

And I want to have a small email icon infront of email address. How can add that?

Answer (score 0):

See, to add small email and phone icons just do a small google search for the image copy its link and paste it in image source. Adjust the size of image as per your requirement.

```
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
```

Check this link, I have added image icon
http://jsfiddle.net/9wa8j/4/

PS:- Dont get scared by seeing the code. Since it contains image url thats why its too long.